# How do you make a javascript function run on selection from this Bootstrap menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently found [some awesome code](http://www.bootply.com/86116) for displaying a scrolling menu, but I am at a complete loss as to how to make a function run by selecting it. Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you for your time and patience.

Right now I am just trying to make an alert pop up upon selection.

Comment: you can use onchange action , so when dropdown change do some stuff

Comment: By selecting you mean on clicking?

Comment: on selection from dropdown

Comment: have a look at my answer. it explains multiple options you have at performing your desired action.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1:**

ADD AN ID `<a href="#" id="mymenu">SHOW ALERT!!!</a>` and then in js attach a click handler function:

```
$('#mymenu').click(function() {
     alert("HELLO WORLD");
   });
```

**METHOD 2:**

There are other possibilities like onclick attribute:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('HELLO WORLD')">SHOW ALERT!!!</a>
```

**METHOD 3:**

OR in the onclick call a function which is defined in js.

```
<a href="#" onclick="myfunc()">SHOW ALERT!!!</a>

<script>
function myfunc(){
    alert("HELLO WORLD");
}
</script>
```

SEE WORKING EXAMPLE OF THE 3 METHODS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mymenu').click(function() {
    alert("HELLO WORLD");
  });
});
```

```css
.scrollable-menu {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootply snippet - Bootstrap Scrollable Dropdown Menu</title>
  <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Bootstrap How to create a scrolling dropdown menu in Bootstrap for large item lists. example snippet for Bootstrap." />
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h2 class="bold">Scrollable Menu</h2>
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Scrollable Menu <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="#" id="mymenu">SHOW ALERT METHOD-1!!!</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#" onclick="alert('HELLO WORLD')">SHOW ALERT METHOD-2!!!</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#" onclick="myfunc()">SHOW ALERT METHOD-3 !!!</a>

                <script>
                  function myfunc() {
                    alert("HELLO WORLD");
                  }
                </script>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```